# How can DotNetOpenAuth help me build an OAuth 2.0 Service Provider?

Tags: .net, dotnetopenauth, oauth-2.0

I'm starting this project where I need to provide authorization for websites. Since I'm starting from scratch, why not use the latest: OAuth 2.0 protocal. Unfortunately, I know nothing about security nor have I implemented OpenID/OAuth. Since I'm used to working in the .NET environment, it's natural for me to find a .NET implementation and that's where DotNetOpenAuth comes in.

However, I'm still not clear on how DotNetOpenAuth can help. I'm coming in with the naive assumption that DotNetOpenAuth will have all the implementation ready and I can just call some functions (to create request tokens, exchange it with access tokens, etc) with all the back-end security, RSA stuff implemented. As I go through the code, it feels like DotNetOpenAuth gives a lot of the interfaces but I still have to code them all up manually.

Can I get a confirmation on this? [Andrew Arnott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46926/andrew-arnott), you there?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997172/oauth-2-0-service-provider-net-libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OAuth 2.0 hasn't been finalized yet, so you may want to consider OAuth 1.0a.  But if you do want to go with OAuth 2.0, be sure you're using the [DotNetOpenAuth 3.5 **CTP**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/CTP/OAuth2/).

Yes, the library takes care of much of the RSA and other protocol details for you.  But you are required to perform some hookup and token persistence yourself since each site is different in those respects.  The CTP download comes with a sample OAuthServiceProvider sample that you may refer to for help.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong here. OAuth 2 is supposed to be simpler to implement for both client and provider because we're removing the need of signatures. However, in both cases of OAuth 1 and OAuth 2, we still need to manually implement those hookups and token persistence that you mentioned. If this is correct, then I would just go with 2.0 but can you please guide me on what I actually need to implement manually?

Comment: Your assessment of OAuth 1.0 vs. 2.0 is roughly correct, although my understanding is that 2.0 supports signatures as well -- it just doesn't require them as 1.0 does.  The CTP download includes samples for how you wire it up to your web site.  It's not complicated.

Comment: ...and actually whether you use 1.0 or 2.0 is roughly the same for you since when signatures apply, the library takes care of it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, Andrew. I would really love to use your library but the fact that I haven't used the latest .NET stuff (MVC, LINQ, etc) is making it so hard. Is there any way you can tell me basic implementation steps?

Comment: @Andrew, a blog post or a screencast showing the process you followed for creating Service Provider and consumer sample would be great?

Comment: Also when I try to download the CTP version with the link you provided, it says access denied.

Comment: @Ismail, I don't know how to explain the access denied, but I updated the link anyway.